# sticky table header not working on angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

i want to fix the mat table header and the last column in the table so i used "sticky" as shown in angular material documentation
here is my html code:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
```

and for the column:

```
                <ng-container matColumnDef="buttons" stickyEnd>
```

after searching i didn't find a solution so i tought it's about the version of angular material i'm using the 8.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Please check the [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-sticky). You can see that it's using the `8.0.2` version of angular material and the stickyness is working just fine.

[image]
Both the `sticky: true` and the `stickyEnd` are set and working fine.

For more help, please fork and edit the stackblitz or provide all your code in the question and I'll help you more.

Answer (score 0):

Your template snippets look fine. Maybe there's something else in your template or in the `CSS` that prevents it from working correctly.

Please have a look at following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ct4ea7?file=src/app/table-sticky-header-example.html) that has both, a sticky header and sticky last column.